# Get first name and email from token in DRF social oauth2

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-rest-framework

I use https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 for my backend. I have a custom user and it works in Django Admin.

My frontend is an iOS app that uses the Facebook SDK to get a token, I have the rights to name and email.

I'm currently testing on localhost without using the app, just using the user token from: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

This is my in `settings.py`:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
'fields': 'id,first_name,last_name'
}
```

When I run

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&backend=facebook&token=<facebook_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: create_user() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'email', 'first_name' and 'last_name'
```

This is leading me to believe that I don't get this information from the token, I got the name from the user before I started using my custom user as auth.

Let me know if it is unclear and I need to provide some code.

Comment: you need to explicitly request it.

Comment: Isn't that what i'm doing in 'SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
'fields': 'id,first_name,last_name'
}'? Or where do i need to request it?